# custom mute ImageButton using boolean keeps changing to true

Tags: android

I am trying to make a mute ImageButton with 2 different background images (sound on and off).

Here is my code

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public boolean IsAudioOn = true;

static AudioManager amanager;
ImageButton playBtn, muteBtn, rulesBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    playBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    muteBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteBtn);
    muteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    rulesBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rulesBtn);
    rulesBtn.setOnClickListener(this);          
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;   

    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.playBtn : 
                        i = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                        break;
    case R.id.rulesBtn :
                        i = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
    case R.id.muteBtn :                 

                        if(IsAudioOn){                                  
                              mute();
                        }
                        else {
                             unmute();
                        }       
    }
}
public void unmute() {
    //for unmute
    amanager = null;
    amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
    amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10, 10);        
    IsAudioOn = true;        
    muteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);        
}

public void mute() {
    // for mute
    amanager = null;
    amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
    amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
    IsAudioOn = false;
    muteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nosound);
    }  }
```

The mute and the changing of the image seems to work properly. The problem is, when I choose one of the other buttons, play and rules, which lead to other activities (after I have pressed mute) and then go back to the StartActivity the boolean IsAudioOn is again true. How can I make the activity "remember" that I have changed it to false?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save instance state because your activity can be destroyed in background and recreated. In this case, your boolean isAudioOn will be reset to true.

For that, override this method

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY, IsAudioOn);
}
```

You could then retrieve this value in your `onCreate` method like this

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    IsAudioOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY, true)
}
```

See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more details.

Don't forget to add the key constant, for example

```
private static final String STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY = "STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY";
```

Comment: I imported the PersistableBundle as eclipse suggested, but it doesn't recognize the STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY. Should I create a constant, local variable or something?

Comment: And should the constant be a sting? Sorry the dummy questions but this is my first try to make an app and I am still learning :)

Comment: Now, when I click the mute button it works and when I go back to the StartActivity the muteBtn background is the image sound. If I do not press the mute again it remember I have it on mute, but if I press it, it mutes again and shows the nosound image as background of the button. What am I doing wrong? I there a way to save on the instance the background of the button as well?

Comment: My new code on the onCreate is: 

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      IsAudioOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_IS_AUDIO_ON_KEY, true); 
      if(IsAudioOn){         
       muteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);
   }
   else {
    muteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nosound);
   } 
  }
  else {
   IsAudioOn = true;
   muteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);
  }